# Java boolean array with one element

Tags: java, arrays, swt, eclipse-rcp, final

So I've come accross this bit of code while scavaging through `org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench`:

```
        final boolean[] initOK = new boolean[1];

        if (getSplash() != null) {

            final boolean[] initDone = new boolean[] { false };
            final Throwable[] error = new Throwable[1];
            Thread initThread = new Thread() {
                /*
                 * (non-Javadoc)
                 * 
                 * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
                 */
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // declare us to be a startup thread so that our
                        // syncs will be executed
                        UISynchronizer.startupThread.set(Boolean.TRUE);
                        initOK[0] = Workbench.this.init();
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        error[0] = e;
                    } finally {
                        initDone[0] = true;
                        display.wake();
                    }
                }
            };
            initThread.start();

          ..............
       }
```

What's the purpose of creating arrays with just one element? Is it faster? I'm definitly missing something here.

Comment: The only advantage of that, which comes to mind is, that you are able to change the first element of this array, but not the array itself, because it's `final`. So for example: You can change the content in an anonymous inner class.

Comment: These variables may be used as parameters of a certain method which accepts array type arguments.

Comment: @Baz Holy crap that's so obvious. Post it as an answer.

Comment: Where is the array used? Probably it is used as a parameter for another call which parameter is an abject Array (void method(Object[] array). - darn, too slow^^

Comment: @MatF It is used in an anonymous class, but it is a *local variable*, thus it has to be final. Since the thread changes the value, it has to be put in a `final` wrapper ===> array.

Comment: Don't get the idea that this is a good programming practice.  Sometimes you have to do things a certain way because ... it works.  Immutability is a good thing in concurrent systems and you should favor the use of immutable objects over mutable ones whenever you possibly can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of using this approach is that the arrays cannot be modified (because they are `final`), however, their content can be changed.

A useful example is that you can use these arrays and modify their first entry in anonymous inner classes without having to make them (`static`) fields.

---

As stated in the comments above, another use-case is that this array can be used to pass it to a method expecting an array type.

Comment: Alternate pattern is to use single-field primitive wrappers, like 'class bool_wrapper { boolean b; }' and then 'final bool_wrapper foo = new bool_wrapper(); foo.b = true; //etc' - essentially the same as case 1, that is providing mutable final objects for primitive types